# Cannot run docker compose.yml file on macOS

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to run compose.yml with:

> docker-compose up

All folders inside are shared for everyone. The error I see is:

> The path: XXX  is not shared from OS X and is not known to Docker. You
>   can configure shared paths from Docker -> Preferences... -> File
>   Sharing. See https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/#namespaces
>   for more info.

My container includes the following locations, tried almost all suggested solution online with no help:

/users

/Volumes

/private

/tmp

/private/var

Comment: why you want to run as sudo?

Comment: Not must actually, the results are the same also without sudo.

Answer (score 0):

I also having the same issue not be during installation process you did not provide several permissions so try reinstall docker machine -- it works for me and please do not use sudo  [image]